# Failed to send batch messages using Firebase REST API

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, dotnet-httpclient

I am experimenting with the REST API for sending batch messages in Firebase Cloud Messaging. I prepared a multipart HTTP request in C#:

```
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "xxx");
request.Content = new StringContent(multicast);
request.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=--subrequest_boundary");
var response = await FcmHttpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

The string value of the `multicast` field above is an HTTP content similar the one provided in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages):

```
--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Authorization: Bearer xxx

POST /v1/projects/myproject/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
  "message":{
     "topic":"global",
     "notification":{
       "title":"FCM Message",
       "body":"This is an FCM notification message to device 0!"
     }
  }
}

--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Authorization: Bearer xxx

POST /v1/projects/myproject/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
  "message":{
     "topic":"readers-club",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Price drop",
       "body":"2% off all books"
     }
  }
}

--subrequest_boundary--
```

Firebase server returns Bad Request-400 with error message: `"Failed to parse batch request, error:  0 items. Received batch body: --subrequest_boundary--"` which indicates that Firebase directly handles the content with the terminating `--subrequest_boundary--`.

What could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

yesterday, i need write bash script to send bath FCM notifaction, and see your code @Ugur, thanks.
now its working, u need change

> Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=--subrequest_boundary

to

> Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=subrequest_boundary

the script

```
#!/bin/bash
curl \
      -X POST \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer [token_auth]" \
      -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=subrequest_boundary" \
      --data-binary @test2.txt \
      https://fcm.googleapis.com/batch
```

and test2.txt, example send 2 notification

```
--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Authorization: Bearer [token_auth]

POST /v1/projects/[project_name_firebase]/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
    "message":{
    "token":"[token_device]",
        "notification":{ 
            "title":"FCM Message",
            "body":"This is an FCM notification message to device 0!",
        }

    }
}

--subrequest_boundary
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Authorization: Bearer [token_auth]

POST /v1/projects/[project_name_firebase]/messages:send
Content-Type: application/json
accept: application/json

{
    "message":{
    "token":"[token_device]",
        "notification":{ 
            "title":"FCM Message",
            "body":"This is an FCM notification message to device 0!",
        }
    }
}

--subrequest_boundary--
```

- change [project_name_firebase] with name your project in firebase
  console example : project_3323.
- change [token_device] with token target device.
- change [token_auth] with your google auth credentials token.

Notification configuration: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidConfig

to get [token_auth]

- java :
  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java_1
- phyton:
  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python_2
- curl:
  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest

code for get [token_auth], getToken.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
client_email="[email_project_firebase]"
service="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
time=3600
scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
private_key=$(echo -ne "[private_key]")

datenow="$(date +%s)"
expired="$(( datenow + time ))";

header='{"alg": "RS256","typ": "JWT"}'
payload='{"iss": "'$client_email'","scope": "'$scope'","aud": "'$service'","exp": '$expired',"iat": '$datenow'}'
HEADEREnc=$( echo -n "${header}" | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n' )
PAYLOADEnc=$( echo -n "${payload}" | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n' )

data="${HEADEREnc}"."${PAYLOADEnc}"
signature=$( openssl dgst -sha256 -sign <(echo -n "${private_key}") <(echo -n "${data}") | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n' )

JWT="${data}"."${signature}"
jsonDataToken=$(curl -d 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion='$JWT https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token)
tokenAuth=$(echo -n $jsonDataToken |grep -Po '"access_token":.*?[^\\]"'|cut -d ':' -f2 |sed 's/"//g')
echo $tokenAuth
```

[email_project_firebase],[private_key] u can get it from file json in "firebase console" -> project name ->  project setting or click gear icon -> account services -> click button "create new secret key"

list scope for other service
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code

```
request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=--subrequest_boundary");
```

to

```
request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed; boundary=subrequest_boundary");
```

Answer (score 0):

The devil's in the details of building the `Content`. You can't simply create a string matching that payload, because certain pieces of it, like the headers and boundaries, are not technically considered part of the body by the `HttpClient` stack.

If you really need to do this with a raw `HttpClient`, take a look at [how the Google APIs .NET client builds and sends a batch request](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis/Requests/BatchRequest.cs). But I suspect that once you realize how cumbersome this is, you're going to conclude that you're best off using a higher-level SDK, such as [firebase-admin-dotnet](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet), which is mentioned in the same documentation you linked to and utilizes Google's .NET client under the hood.