# sending fcm notification messages to multiple android devices by registration_ids parameter

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications to multiple android devices(where same app is installed) by fcm from php server side by calling this url -

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

I checked sending messages to [device groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) but my requirement is such that there will not be definite devices to which i will send messages because i am going to do it in a hourly cron job, and each time a cron job runs it will send notification messages to different different devices according to requirements. or can it be done in another way?

But i am thinking to use **"registration_ids"** parameter instead of **"to"** parameter, details of these fields [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) in the Downstream HTTP messages section. In this registration_ids field i will put all required device registration tokens in array. Now my question is after receiving message in android device can the message be parsed in the android app sdk codes?. i am in a bit of doubt as in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple) there are no mentions of registration_ids parameter when sending messages to multiple android devices. Please assure me. And furthermore, will the message be sent when android app is in background?!. Please don't write one line, provide some examples if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for [building requests to send to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices) you will find an example of passing multiple FCM tokens in a single call to the FCM API in the `tokens` parameter (in Node.js) or by using a HTTP batch request with multiple subrequests (in the REST API).

If you're having a hard time making this work, posting a question that [shows what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) increases the chances that someone can help making it work.

---

Yes, the message is **sent** regardless of whether the app is in the foreground, or in background. Whether the notification is actually shown depends on many more factors, many of which are outside of your control (such as the Android version, device maker/OEM, and the user settings).

Comment: so "registration_ids" parameter also works, is not it serves the purpose like REST batch request? my concentration was on legacy http api - https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send not v1 http api, i think batch request using v1 http api.

Comment: On the legacy API you can indeed pass `registration_ids`. Good to hear you got it working. 

Comment: Yes but with "registration_ids" i can't include separate message body parameters per message.when legacy api expires?. I will soon switch to v1 http api, this batch request seems using a batch_request.txt file which seems a headache coz i will be needed to set token dynamically per request not any predefined device token.

Comment: There are currently no plans to retire the legacy API, but active development will focus on the newer versioned API. The request doesn't need to be a text **file**, but (as with all HTTP requests) it is a textual request.

Comment: Can you plz help how do i create a http batch request with all these sub requests by php?google search not helping me. Does a batch request sends all requests at the same time parallelly like curl multi call or one after another sequentially?. If i use curl multi then will it be same as batch request.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600330/failed-to-send-batch-messages-using-firebase-rest-api and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=HTTP+batch+request+php+subrequest_boundary

Comment: I have this [Laravel package](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase) for the Firebase PHP Admin SDK. It has classes for message sending to multiple devices as summarized in this [documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/cloud-messaging.html), i tested 2 messages sending and it working although took some time. Am i on the right track on sending multiple devices fcm messaging using cloud messaging classes of this firebase admin sdk php package https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase ??